# Why is this div column not going all the way to the right?

Tags: html, css

Strangly enough, my website is rendering fine in Internet Explorer but fails in Mozilla based browsers.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Does anyone see why "right-panel" does not go all the way to the right?  You can see how it is not lined up with the right edge of "top-panel":

```
#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 750px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#top-panel
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 88px;
}

#left-panel
{
     padding-top: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     border-right: 1px dashed #000000;
     float: left;
     width: 250px;
}

#right-panel
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    width: 449px;
}

.clear
{
    clear:both;
    line-height:0;
}
```

If anyone wants to see the actual site it is: [Math Relay](http://www.math-cs.ucmo.edu/~MDM60250/mathrelay/)

Comment: try removing this and see if it if lines up: padding-left: 10px; That might do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you apply **width:100%** and use **padding-left:10px** also, it computes the width first, and then applies the padding, so actually your **#top_panel** CSS declaration is the problem. Try setting it to a fixed width for that.

Comment: Where _it_ in the above statement refers to Firefox, but not IE6. (Which is why the posted page looks OK in IE6)

Comment: Note that with a DOCTYPE IE6 uses the correct CSS box model, that is the width of and element is the sum of its width, border, and padding. Without a DOCTYPE IE6 goes into quirks mode and uses a box model where "width" sets width in its entirety. Note that ALL modern browsers use the former box model.

Answer (score 2):

it is the padding-left:10px; in the #top-panel

Set that to 0 and you'll see them line up.

Try using FireBug, that's how i found the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The Padding-Left:10px is causing an extra 10 pixels to appear on the right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of the other answers, but hopefully explaining what's happening behind the scenes, too:

The `width: 100%` on `#top-panel` refers to the width of the div's content area, excluding borders, padding and margin.  Thus, when you specify both `width: 100%` and `padding-left: 10px` the width of `#top-panel` including padding is actually 10px + 750px (the padding plus 100% of the width of `#container`.)

The best solution in my opinion is to remove `width: 100%` from `#top-panel`.  This will make the div take up the entire width of the parent element withut overflowing the `#container`.

The page looks ok in Internet Explorer since IE incorrectly includes padding and border when calculating the width of the div if the page is rendered in quirks mode.  More details about this bug can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

Answer (score 1):

It's your `#top-panel` that's `10px` bigger that your `#container` because of your `padding-left: 10px;`

Just add `10px` to your `#container` and it will be good.

Comment: i don't think you want to adjust #container to fit the cnotent, but rather to fit your content(#top_panel) properly inside your #container.

Comment: @jaywon +1: Exactly.  Actually, 10px to `#container` won't do any good at all - `#top-panel` will still take up the width of `#container` plus an additional 10 pixels and overflow the new width.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width: 100%` from `#top-panel`.